# Plotting ODE with different arguments in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, ode, differential-equations

I would like to plot this differential equation dAdt = r-c*A, making different plots for different values for c

```
#where 
c = cs(BW/70)^K
```

This is how I calculated my c array

```
Height = [58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76]
K = 0.75
cs = 0.35
BW = [103,106.5,110,113.5,117.5,121,125,129,133,137,141.5,145,149.5,154,158.5,163,167,172,176.5] 
BW_1 = []

for i in range(0, len(BW)):
    BW_1.append(cs*(BW[i]/70)**K)
print(BW_1)
```

code 2- The code I have to solve my ODE with one c value

```
#Function that returns dA/dt
h = 7
def model(A,t):
    c=0.35
    r=10 if t < h else 0
    dAdt = r-c*A
    return dAdt

#initial condition 
A0=10

#time points 
t=np.linspace(0,20)

#solve ODE
A= odeint(model,A0,t)

#Plot 
plt.plot(t,A)
plt.xlabel('time(h)')
plt.ylabel('Amount of drug in the body, A(t) (mg)')
plt.show()
```

But I would like to plot multiple plots for my array of c values, how would I go about this?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71811537/graphing-piecewise-differential-equation-in-matplotlib

Comment: Hi, there isn't a question here, just some code you've written. Please update your post with an actual question you need help with. For instance, if this doesn't do what you think it should, describe what it *does* do, and then we can suggest ways to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass a list of c's as a parameter to your `model` function:

```
h = 7
def model(A,t, c_values):
    r=10 if t < h else 0
    dAdt_values = [r-c*A for c in c_values]
    return dAdt
```

Then if you want to make different plots just select the correct index of `dAdt` which will return the array of data you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just as you used a loop to compute `BW_1`, you can also loop to produce different plots.

```
def model(A,t,c,h):
    r=10 if t < h else 0
    dAdt = r-c*A
    return dAdt

#time points 
t=np.linspace(0,20)
#initial condition 
A0=10

for bw in BW:
    c= cs*(bw/70)**K
    
    #solve ODE
    A= odeint(model,A0,t, args=(c,h))
    
    #Plot 
    plt.plot(t,A, lw=1)

plt.xlabel('time(h)')
plt.ylabel('Amount of drug in the body, A(t) (mg)')
plt.show()
```

[image: family of plots]